# Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException: Unable to decode image from file (/tmp/GlideYgGwCS)

Tags: laravel

I have some code that's working locally. In production I get the following error:

```
Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException: Unable to decode image from file (/tmp/GlideYgGwCS)
```

The `/tmp/GlideYgGwCS` seems to indicate that it tries to read the file from a temp directory, at least judging from `Intervention\Image\Gd\Decoder` line 82 `"Unable to decode image from file ({$path})."` from where the exception is thrown.

But the file is actually stored locally on the server as you'll see from the code below. I'm sure there is something wrong with the path that I'm providing.

The code:

```php
// First the file is stored to disk coming from an API response
// I have tested this extensively, and checked this in production, and the file 
// is returned and is stored correctly

$disk = Storage::disk('local');

$date = now()->toDateString();

$fileName = str()->uuid();

// $reponse comes from an API, this is tested and working
$disk->put($date.'/folder-name/'.$fileName.'.png', $response->getBody(), 'public');

// A few moments later...

$path = Storage::disk('local')->path($date.'/folder-name/'.$fileName.'.png');

$post = Post::findOrFail(1);

// Then this is where the error is thrown
// This is using the Spatie Media Library package, but it looks like it's unrelated to that
$post->addMedia($path)
  ->preservingOriginal()
  ->toMediaCollection('photos');
```

I have tested both locally and on production that the `.png` file is stored correctly.

As indicated this is working locally, but maybe I should use something different than `Storage::disk('local')->path()` to get the file to pass to the `addMedia` method?

Update: regarding driver, this is the output when running `php -i | grep 'GD\|ImageMagick'`

Locally

```
GD Support => enabled
GD headers Version => 2.3.3
GD library Version => 2.3.3
```

On the server

```
GD Support => enabled
GD headers Version => 2.3.3
GD library Version => 2.3.3
Imagick compiled with ImageMagick version => ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16 x86_64 20190101 https://imagemagick.org
Imagick using ImageMagick library version => ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16 x86_64 20190101 https://imagemagick.org
ImageMagick copyright => © 1999-2019 ImageMagick Studio LLC
ImageMagick release date => 20190101
ImageMagick number of supported formats:  => 235
ImageMagick supported formats => 3FR, 3G2, 3GP, AAI, AI, ART, ARW, AVI, AVS, BGR, BGRA, BGRO, BIE, BMP, BMP2, BMP3, BRF, CAL, CALS, CANVAS, CAPTION, CIN, CIP, CLIP, CMYK, CMYKA, CR2, CRW, CUR, CUT, DATA, DCM, DCR, DCX, DDS, DFONT, DJVU, DNG, DOT, DPX, DXT1, DXT5, EPDF, EPI, EPS, EPS2, EPS3, EPSF, EPSI, EPT, EPT2, EPT3, ERF, EXR, FAX, FILE, FITS, FRACTAL, FTP, FTS, G3, G4, GIF, GIF87, GRADIENT, GRAY, GRAYA, GROUP4, GV, H, HALD, HDR, HISTOGRAM, HRZ, HTM, HTML, HTTP, HTTPS, ICB, ICO, ICON, IIQ, INFO, INLINE, IPL, ISOBRL, ISOBRL6, JBG, JBIG, JNG, JNX, JPE, JPEG, JPG, JPS, JSON, K25, KDC, LABEL, M2V, M4V, MAC, MAGICK, MAP, MASK, MAT, MATTE, MEF, MIFF, MKV, MNG, MONO, MOV, MP4, MPC, MPEG, MPG, MRW, MSL, MSVG, MTV, MVG, NEF, NRW, NULL, ORF, OTB, OTF, PAL, PALM, PAM, PANGO, PATTERN, PBM, PCD, PCDS, PCL, PCT, PCX, PDB, PDF, PDFA, PEF, PES, PFA, PFB, PFM, PGM, PGX, PICON, PICT, PIX, PJPEG, PLASMA, PNG, PNG00, PNG24, PNG32, PNG48, PNG64, PNG8, PNM, PPM, PREVIEW, PS, PS2, PS3, PSB, PSD, PTIF, PWP, RADIAL-GRADIENT, RAF, RAS, RAW, RGB, RGBA, RGBO, RGF, RLA, RLE, RMF, RW2, SCR, SCT, SFW, SGI, SHTML, SIX, SIXEL, SPARSE-COLOR, SR2, SRF, STEGANO, SUN, SVG, SVGZ, TEXT, TGA, THUMBNAIL, TIFF, TIFF64, TILE, TIM, TTC, TTF, TXT, UBRL, UBRL6, UIL, UYVY, VDA, VICAR, VID, VIFF, VIPS, VST, WBMP, WEBP, WMF, WMV, WMZ, WPG, X, X3F, XBM, XC, XCF, XPM, XPS, XV, XWD, YCbCr, YCbCrA, YUV
```

Comment: Have you tried to use imagick driver instead of gd ?

Comment: @Vins I have added the output when checking for the driver locally and on the server. Not sure what this means though :-)

Comment: Can you try to check if `File::exists($path);` return true ?

Comment: I can try, it's a bit tricky given this is only happening on production. What I do have is `if (empty($path))` which returns `false`, but that's not very solid I realize now so let me try with `File::exists`. But I'm pretty sure the path is incorrect given the error indicates that `/tmp/` in the pathname?

Comment: Can you also test to get the **path** with **storage_path** method ?

Comment: Everything works now, no clue why... The only change I made was adding `File::exists` as a check, but given it doesn't return `false` the rest is the same. I checked locally and `storage_path` and `Storage::disk()->path()` return the exact same strings. The only thing I can think of is that Horizon was not properly restarted after deploy, as most of the code mentioned is happening in a job.